# How to add products to cart similar to related products?

Tags: magento2

For a client we have a case where we want to be able to add products to the cart in the same way you do with related products using checkboxes on a PDP (default magento).
When I look at the code for the related products it looks like this:

```
<div class="field choice related"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox17" name="related_products[]" value="17">
    <label class="label" for="related-checkbox17">
    <span>Add to Cart</span></label>
</div>
```

I don't see any additional javascript and it is not part of any form. I don't understand how this magically works, I think it has something to do with name="related_products[]". There is also no SKU to be found here. When I add similar code on the PDP it does not work. What is the underlying mechanism here? What are the minimal requirements to make it work? When the user clicks on the add to cart button it should add those extra products to the cart in addition to the main product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related product template (`Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml`) is using the following JS file : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/related-products.js`.

In this file we can see Magento is using a function `_addRelatedToProduct` whenever a checkbox is clicked :

```js
$(this.options.relatedCheckbox, this.element).on('click', $.proxy(this._addRelatedToProduct, this));
```

When it happens, Magento will retrieve all the selected checkbox, and add it to the `#related-products-field` hidden input (here `this.options.relatedProductsField`) :

```js
_addRelatedToProduct: function () {
    $(this.options.relatedProductsField).val(
        $(this.options.relatedCheckbox + ':checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(',')
    );
},
```

This hidden input is present in the main product form (`Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml`). This field will be sent to the controller when the customer add the product to the cart, because it is part of the form which is submitted.

```
    <form data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSubmitUrl($_product)) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()) :?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= (int)$_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item"  value="<?= (int)$block->getRequest()->getParam('id') ?>" />
        <!-- ... -->
```

Then on the controller side (`\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add`), Magento retrieves it and add them to the cart :

```php
// ...
$related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
// ...
if (!empty($related)) {
    $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
}
// ...
```

This is how Magento manage to add this related products to the cart at the same time than the main product.

You should take a look at this process to do a similar one on your specific case.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have it working now after adding some extra customisation. Also created a mixin for validate-product.js in order to add some custom validation (the has to select at least one option).

Comment: Looking back I'm not sure whether I should have used the related products functionality based on the requirements of the client. This is obviously not your fault. It is definitely the easiest solution but it kinda feels like a hacky one. I sure think it would be possible to create a stand-alone solution without having to misuse the related products functionality and product validator like I now have done.